# How can I connect mysql to Amundsen Lyft?

Tags: python, elasticsearch, lyft-api

I'm working on the PoC about Amundsen Lyft for introducing data catalog.
So, I use the file 'sample_mysql_loader.py' and insert database information.
OS: Ubuntu 18.04
Python: 3.6.9
pip: 21.3.1
elasticsearch: 8.0.0
neo4j: 3.5.26

I installed Amundsen Lyft using quickstart on Docker

```
import logging
import sys
import textwrap
import uuid

from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
from pyhocon import ConfigFactory
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base

from databuilder.extractor.mysql_metadata_extractor import MysqlMetadataExtractor
from databuilder.extractor.neo4j_extractor import Neo4jExtractor
from databuilder.extractor.neo4j_search_data_extractor import Neo4jSearchDataExtractor
from databuilder.extractor.sql_alchemy_extractor import SQLAlchemyExtractor
from databuilder.job.job import DefaultJob
from databuilder.loader.file_system_elasticsearch_json_loader import FSElasticsearchJSONLoader
from databuilder.loader.file_system_neo4j_csv_loader import FsNeo4jCSVLoader
from databuilder.publisher import neo4j_csv_publisher
from databuilder.publisher.elasticsearch_publisher import ElasticsearchPublisher
from databuilder.publisher.neo4j_csv_publisher import Neo4jCsvPublisher
from databuilder.task.task import DefaultTask
from databuilder.transformer.base_transformer import NoopTransformer

import pymysql
pymysql.install_as_MySQLdb()


es_host = None
neo_host = None
if len(sys.argv) > 1:
    es_host = sys.argv[1]
if len(sys.argv) > 2:
    neo_host = sys.argv[2]

es = Elasticsearch([
    {'host': es_host or 'localhost'},
])

DB_FILE = '/tmp/test.db'
SQLITE_CONN_STRING = 'sqlite:////tmp/test.db'
Base = declarative_base()

NEO4J_ENDPOINT = f'bolt://{neo_host or "localhost"}:7687'

neo4j_endpoint = NEO4J_ENDPOINT

neo4j_user = 'neo4j'
neo4j_password = 'test'

LOGGER = logging.getLogger(__name__)


# todo: connection string needs to change
def connection_string():
    ***user = 'user_name'
    password='password'
    host = 'host'
    port = 'port'
    db = 'db_name'***

    return "mysql://%s:%s@%s:%s/%s" % (user, ***password,***  host, port, db)


def run_mysql_job():
    where_clause_suffix = textwrap.dedent("""
        where c.table_schema = '***db_name***'
    """)

    tmp_folder = '/var/tmp/amundsen/table_metadata'
    node_files_folder = f'{tmp_folder}/nodes/'
    relationship_files_folder = f'{tmp_folder}/relationships/'

    job_config = ConfigFactory.from_dict({
        f'extractor.mysql_metadata.{MysqlMetadataExtractor.WHERE_CLAUSE_SUFFIX_KEY}': where_clause_suffix,
        f'extractor.mysql_metadata.{MysqlMetadataExtractor.USE_CATALOG_AS_CLUSTER_NAME}': True,
        f'extractor.mysql_metadata.extractor.sqlalchemy.{SQLAlchemyExtractor.CONN_STRING}': connection_string(),
        f'loader.filesystem_csv_neo4j.{FsNeo4jCSVLoader.NODE_DIR_PATH}': node_files_folder,
        f'loader.filesystem_csv_neo4j.{FsNeo4jCSVLoader.RELATION_DIR_PATH}': relationship_files_folder,
        f'publisher.neo4j.{neo4j_csv_publisher.NODE_FILES_DIR}': node_files_folder,
        f'publisher.neo4j.{neo4j_csv_publisher.RELATION_FILES_DIR}': relationship_files_folder,
        f'publisher.neo4j.{neo4j_csv_publisher.NEO4J_END_POINT_KEY}': neo4j_endpoint,
        f'publisher.neo4j.{neo4j_csv_publisher.NEO4J_USER}': neo4j_user,
        f'publisher.neo4j.{neo4j_csv_publisher.NEO4J_PASSWORD}': neo4j_password,
        f'publisher.neo4j.{neo4j_csv_publisher.JOB_PUBLISH_TAG}': 'unique_tag',  # should use unique tag here like {ds}
    })
    job = DefaultJob(conf=job_config,
                     task=DefaultTask(extractor=MysqlMetadataExtractor(), loader=FsNeo4jCSVLoader()),
                     publisher=Neo4jCsvPublisher())

    return job


def create_es_publisher_sample_job(elasticsearch_index_alias='table_search_index',
                                   elasticsearch_doc_type_key='table',
                                   model_name='databuilder.models.table_elasticsearch_document.TableESDocument',
                                   cypher_query=None,
                                   elasticsearch_mapping=None):
    """
    :param elasticsearch_index_alias:  alias for Elasticsearch used in
                                       amundsensearchlibrary/search_service/config.py as an index
    :param elasticsearch_doc_type_key: name the ElasticSearch index is prepended with. Defaults to `table` resulting in
                                       `table_search_index`
    :param model_name:                 the Databuilder model class used in transporting between Extractor and Loader
    :param cypher_query:               Query handed to the `Neo4jSearchDataExtractor` class, if None is given (default)
                                       it uses the `Table` query baked into the Extractor
    :param elasticsearch_mapping:      Elasticsearch field mapping "DDL" handed to the `ElasticsearchPublisher` class,
                                       if None is given (default) it uses the `Table` query baked into the Publisher
    """
    # loader saves data to this location and publisher reads it from here
    extracted_search_data_path = '/var/tmp/amundsen/search_data.json'

    task = DefaultTask(loader=FSElasticsearchJSONLoader(),
                       extractor=Neo4jSearchDataExtractor(),
                       transformer=NoopTransformer())


    # elastic search client instance
    elasticsearch_client = es
    # unique name of new index in Elasticsearch
    elasticsearch_new_index_key = 'tables' + str(uuid.uuid4())

    job_config = ConfigFactory.from_dict({
        f'extractor.search_data.extractor.neo4j.{Neo4jExtractor.GRAPH_URL_CONFIG_KEY}': neo4j_endpoint,
        f'extractor.search_data.extractor.neo4j.{Neo4jExtractor.MODEL_CLASS_CONFIG_KEY}': model_name,
        f'extractor.search_data.extractor.neo4j.{Neo4jExtractor.NEO4J_AUTH_USER}': neo4j_user,
        f'extractor.search_data.extractor.neo4j.{Neo4jExtractor.NEO4J_AUTH_PW}': neo4j_password,
        f'loader.filesystem.elasticsearch.{FSElasticsearchJSONLoader.FILE_PATH_CONFIG_KEY}': extracted_search_data_path,
        f'loader.filesystem.elasticsearch.{FSElasticsearchJSONLoader.FILE_MODE_CONFIG_KEY}': 'w',
        f'publisher.elasticsearch.{ElasticsearchPublisher.FILE_PATH_CONFIG_KEY}': extracted_search_data_path,
        f'publisher.elasticsearch.{ElasticsearchPublisher.FILE_MODE_CONFIG_KEY}': 'r',
        f'publisher.elasticsearch.{ElasticsearchPublisher.ELASTICSEARCH_CLIENT_CONFIG_KEY}':
            elasticsearch_client,
        f'publisher.elasticsearch.{ElasticsearchPublisher.ELASTICSEARCH_NEW_INDEX_CONFIG_KEY}':
            elasticsearch_new_index_key,
        f'publisher.elasticsearch.{ElasticsearchPublisher.ELASTICSEARCH_DOC_TYPE_CONFIG_KEY}':
            elasticsearch_doc_type_key,
        f'publisher.elasticsearch.{ElasticsearchPublisher.ELASTICSEARCH_ALIAS_CONFIG_KEY}':
            elasticsearch_index_alias,
    })

    # only optionally add these keys, so need to dynamically `put` them
    if cypher_query:
        job_config.put(f'extractor.search_data.{Neo4jSearchDataExtractor.CYPHER_QUERY_CONFIG_KEY}',
                       cypher_query)
    if elasticsearch_mapping:
        job_config.put(f'publisher.elasticsearch.{ElasticsearchPublisher.ELASTICSEARCH_MAPPING_CONFIG_KEY}',
                       elasticsearch_mapping)

    job = DefaultJob(conf=job_config,
                     task=task,
                     publisher=ElasticsearchPublisher())

    return job


if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Uncomment next line to get INFO level logging
    # logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)

    loading_job = run_mysql_job()
    loading_job.launch()

    job_es_table = create_es_publisher_sample_job(
        elasticsearch_index_alias='table_search_index',
        elasticsearch_doc_type_key='table',
        model_name='databuilder.models.table_elasticsearch_document.TableESDocument')
    job_es_table.launch()
```

But, I got the error message below. How can I connect my database to Amundsen Lyft?

```
elasticsearch.exceptions.RequestError: RequestError(400, 'mapper_parsing_exception', 'Root mapping definition has unsupported parameters:  [table : {properties={schema={analyzer=simple, type=text, fields={raw={type=keyword}}}, cluster={type=text}, description={analyzer=simple, type=text}, display_name={type=keyword}, column_descriptions={analyzer=simple, type=text}, programmatic_descriptions={analyzer=simple, type=text}, tags={type=keyword}, badges={type=keyword}, database={analyzer=simple, type=text, fields={raw={type=keyword}}}, total_usage={type=long}, name={analyzer=simple, type=text, fields={raw={type=keyword}}}, last_updated_timestamp={format=epoch_second, type=date}, unique_usage={type=long}, column_names={analyzer=simple, type=text, fields={raw={type=keyword}}}, key={type=keyword}}}]')
```